# Django downloading a file that had been uploaded before

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10 and I have a button on my home page that you can click to download a file (PDF or MP4). I have a ajax call going to my views.py

```
`def downloadfile(request):
    if request.POST:
        fileviewing = get_object_or_404(FileViewing, pk=request.POST.get("id"))
        file_name = fileviewing.file.file.name
        file_path = fileviewing.file.file.path
        file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
        file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
        response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype)
        response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
        response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
        return response`
```

This is my function to download a file but nothing happens when it goes through the fuction. There are no errors and the function runs completely but nothing is being downloaded.